# Code generation for FocusHelper failed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I removed some unwanted image resources first from my *vb.net* form and then from the resources in the explorer, now every time I debug or try to save it is giving me error:
`"Code Generation for property FocusHelper Failed"`
along with the deleted images path that it could not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

1. In "Solution Explorer" pane, click "Show all files" icon.
2. Expand "My Project" > "Resources.resx" and double click "Resources.Designer.vb".
3. Locate and remove the property "FocusHelper".
4. Rebuild project.

**Option 2**

1. Press "Ctrl + F" or click "Edit" > "Quick Find".
2. Write "FocusHelper" in the "Find what" textbox and set "Look in" to "Entire Solution".
3. Uncheck all "Find options"
4. Click "Find next" and remove any references found.
5. Rebuild project.

**Option 3**

1. Close and reopen VS.
2. Open and rebuild project.

**Note**

Also, I strongly suggest you [turn strict ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c553zwz0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: "FocusHelper" property is not present in "Resources.Designer.vb".

Comment: Thanks a lot,the last option worked for me,and the second one is the same as I did for the first option.

Comment: @Kbhatt So this fixed your problem? :)

Comment: lol yes,I was worried because the saving was also not possible due to the error message I got  so did not try closing and opening VS at first.

Comment: @Kbhatt Hehe, I can see why;) Please accept this as an answer as others might find it useful. Also, you'll get some rep points and a badge. :D